# Can you begin a sentence with 'It's because...'

Tags: grammar, sentence

Someone I work with in an ESL setting is using "It's because..." to begin his sentences and I believe it doesn't sound natural. I am aware that he should be using 'because' to join the sentences but for argument sake I want to know if it is grammatically correct to begin a sentence with "It's because".

An example:

I want to become a fireman.

**It's because** I want to help people who are in need.

Or

I think students should use eletronic dictionaries. **It's because** they are more convenient.

Comment: What reason do you have for asserting that it doesn't sound natural? Have you Googled the term, or consulted corpuses of English usage?

Comment: The sentences in question are grammatically correct, and convey the proper meaning. That said, using it *all the time* might be a bit much. One may begin a sentence with practically any word or phrase and manage to make it correct in a grammatical sense.

Comment: While they are correct, when written (as opposed to spoken) the examples appear to end rather abruptly. "I want to become a fireman because..." or "It's because I want to help people in need *that* I want to become a fireman" or even just doing the "It's because" seem more fluent to me.

Answer (score 5):

The sentence "it's because..." is grammatically correct. The pronoun *it* refers to the preceding sentence, "I want to become a fireman". Using substitution, we get "I want to become a fireman because...". It isn't necessarily the most fluid or succinct method of writing, but it isn't wrong either.

Of course, it's important to ensure the referent for "it" is clear, [as always](https://web.archive.org/web/20220324113623/https://webapps.towson.edu/ows/proref.htm).

I agree splitting the single thought process into two sentences seems a little unnatural. However, there are cases where it makes sense. One example is after a rhetorical question, with a full stop for dramatic effect:

> Why do we take air for granted?
> It's because...

Answer (score -3):

Proper grammar would be "I would like to become a fireman because...". Sometimes if you're stuck with how to word a sentence try flipping it around!

Comment: This doesn't really answer the question at hand, which asks about the grammaticallity of starting a sentence with "it is because".